# Unable to pass data in between python files

Tags: python, multithreading, simulation

I am running a python program which has 5 files and these are main.py , visual.py and utils.py , sharedState.py and GUILogtask1f1.py. In my visual.py file there are two classes and inside I have several functions. In order to make a simulation I am using threading .

It's a simulation system that run completely fine. When I run main.py simulation create , delete , print customer data simultinuously. Problem arise when i run the GUIlogtask1F1.py. It was created to show current scenario of lanes , amount of people and required time needed to process all. For this i need to get the updated lanes data from visual.py . So when user press the button from pop up window to check current status, print_value() function will be called. After some calculation it will print the data in console. I tried several ways . But cant get the updated lanes data. However i managed to get the initial arrays which are empty.

For better understanding i used comment that explain each function about their functionalities.
I shared almost all my code here skipping some non important functions in two files.

My Code look like this:

sharedState.py

```
is_done = True #if false the thread will stop working
l7 = 0  #the length of waiting line
l_curr = [0,0,0,0,0,0] #the value of each index represent the number of customer in active lanes
```

visual.py

```
import time
import copy
from datetime import datetime
from sharedState import l_curr, l7
import sharedState 


lane1 = [] #regular lane
lane2 = [] #regular lane
lane3 = [] #regular lane
lane4 = [] #regular lane
lane5 = [] #regular lane
lane6 = [] #self service lane
lane7 = [] #waiting lane




class LaneManipulation: #This class hold the function that will insert customers to lane following criatria
    #insert customer in the lanes
    #this function is called from generate_customer function under utils.py file
    #every time customer generates and sent them to this function
    def insertCustomer(self,a): 
        global l7
        from utils import  Lottery 

        lane_inst = Lane_situation() 
        lane_inst.print_stat()#this will print the situation of different lanes

        #this function will insert customer in lane1,lane2,lane3,......,lane7 based on different critaria 

#each function is responsible for the deletion of customer one by one from their lane
#point to be noted each of these function is running in background using threads declared in main.py
#later i will share main.py
    def clearing_lane1(self):
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane1) > 0:
                lane1.pop(0)
                time.sleep(4)

    def clearing_lane2(self):
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane2) > 0:
        
    def clearing_lane3(self):
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane3) > 0:
    
    def clearing_lane4(self):
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane4) > 0:


    def clearing_lane5(self):
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane5) > 0:

    def clearing_lane6(self): 
        while sharedState.is_done:
            if len(lane6) > 0:



#Thi is the last class that print the situation of lanes and called inside insertCustomer function
class Lane_situation:    

    def print_stat(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
```

code from utils.py

```
import random
import time
import sharedState  
from visual import LaneManipulation

#these function under Create_customerElement element generate customers 
#and products in their bucket ,send them to insertCustomer function from visual.py 
class Create_customerElement:

    def generate_prod(self,customer_number):
        customer_with_basket_items = [random.randint(1, 30) for _ in range(customer_number)]
        return customer_with_basket_items

#the function called generate_customer is also under threading process so that it can produce customer  #after 30 sec which is also called in main.py

    def generate_customer(self): 
        insert_ins = LaneManipulation()
        while sharedState.is_done:
            customer_number = random.randint(1,10)
            cus_with_prod = self.generate_prod(customer_number)
            insert_ins.insertCustomer(cus_with_prod)
            time.sleep(30)
```

code from main.py

```
import sharedState
import threading
from utils import Create_customerElement
from visual import Lane_services


customer_ins = Create_customerElement()
service_ins = Lane_services()

#This main.py function is able run the whole system nicely 
#these are the threads that are needed  to be run during the hole time of simulation
#clearing lanes(all 6 function from visual.py) function are working together as long as each of the lane has customer

service_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane1)
service_thread2 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane2)
service_thread3 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane3)
service_thread4 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane4)
service_thread5 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane5)
service_thread6 = threading.Thread(target=service_ins.clearing_lane6)
generateThred = threading.Thread(target=customer_ins.generate_customer)




generateThred.start()
service_thread1.start()
service_thread2.start()
service_thread3.start()
service_thread4.start()
service_thread5.start()
service_thread6.start()


# sharedState.is_done = False

service_thread1.join()
service_thread2.join()
service_thread3.join()
service_thread4.join()
service_thread5.join()
service_thread6.join()
generateThred.join()
```

code from GUIlogtask1F1.py:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
import multiprocessing
import visual
import sharedState

#so purpose of this file is when someone run this file and a pop up window will shown with some button
#one of them is print lanes overall situation on its console. So i need to get the data of lane1 to lane7 so that i can show when someone press button2 
#But my problem arise when i try to import arrays from visual.py i only get the initial empty array [],[],[],[]....
#But i need latest update lanes situation so that i can show them . No matter how i try i failed every way possible



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("550x500")
root.title("GUI Simulation")


def close_GUI():
    root.destroy()

import visual

def print_value():
    print(visual.lane1,visual.lane2,visual.lane3,visual.lane4)



# create a label as a heading of this window
label = tk.Label(root, text="This is a simulation window for \n Supermarket lane simulation project",
                 font=('Arial', 14))
label.pack(pady=10)

# create frame to hold all the buttons
btnFrame = tk.Frame(root)
btnFrame.columnconfigure(0)
btnFrame.columnconfigure(1)

# create buttons & place them properly using rows and column in grid()
button1 = tk.Button(btnFrame, text="Start Simulation", font=('Arial',14))
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

button2 = tk.Button(btnFrame, text="Lane Status", font=('Arial',14),command=print_value)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

# button3 = tk.Button(btnFrame, text="Stop Simulation", font=('Arial',14))
# button3.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

# button4 = tk.Button(btnFrame, text="Exit", font=('Arial',14), command=close_GUI)
# button4.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=15, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

btnFrame.pack(pady=30) # end of the frame

# create the main event loop
root.mainloop()
```

It would be great if some one show me ways how can i get updated values from visual.py to GUIlogtasf1.py (hobe data transition is realtime so customer can see real time update).

Hope will be kind enough to ignore my mistake in english.

Thanks you.

Comment: Are you reassigning the `lane#` variables anywhere in `visual`, or are the lane list objects changed completely via mutations?

Comment: no re assignment. The functions are responsible for updating the lists

Comment: Files are static, inanimate objects, so talking about passing data between files is not very expressive because the files might be invoked as modules, or threads or processes. Maybe you could think more in terms of passing data between processes, or threads, or objects, or dialogs...